# Where I must put .po/.mo wordpress languages file?

Tags: wordpress, po, mo

I download a wordpress theme that have a language folder with .po and .mo files, I translate these files with POEdit and replace with originals. but any words in theme didn't translate.

I think I must put files in another place, In theme help I didn't find any useful answer.

please help me.

my files: fa_IR.mo and fa_IR.po
in my wp-config: `define('WPLANG', 'fa_IR');`

I step by step follow [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language) but it don't change and don't shown my translation.

Comment: I would suggest you simply [Refer to The Friendly Manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I just edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Wordpress to properly find your localization files, they have to be in the directory specified in either the second argument of [`load_theme_textdomain`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain) or the third of [`load_plugin_textdomain`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain).

Be careful that your .mo files **must** be named **exactly like the locale**. In your case it has to be `fa_IR.mo`. In the case of a plugin, the name of the plugin must be prefixed to the locale with a dash, such as: `my-plugin-fa_IR.mo`.

Comment: I have these codes in function.php `add_action('after_setup_theme', 'bellissima_theme_setup');
function bellissima_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain('bellissima', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}`

Comment: Then you can just put your `fa_IR.mo` file inside `wp-content/themes/bellissima/languages`.

Comment: yes I put it there, but no works

Comment: That's bizarre, also because the `after_setup_theme` is run on every page load. Are you sure your `.mo` file was generated correctly? Not the `.po`, mind you, but the `.mo`. Try to deactivate and reactivate your theme, perhaps.

Comment: deactivate and reactivate worked, thank you